# Clone não clona o repositório remoto desejado, sempre clona o mesmo repositório já clonado anteriormente por mim(calculadorateste)

Tags: git

estou tentando executar no terminal do Mac o cmd clone(***git clone + chave SSH copiada***) de um repositório remoto XX via chave SSH para o meu repositório local, no terminal ele executa o cmd clone corretamente, informando que o repositório XX remoto foi clonado, porém ao verificar a pasta clonada no meu laptop, consta sempre um projeto já clonado por mim anteriormente (calculadorateste), já tentei fazer isso para vários outros repositórios remotos, mas agora sempre aparece na pasta clonada o meu projeto/pasta "calculadorateste". O que deve fazer para clonar corretamente o que eu quero clonar e não ficar repetindo a clonagem calculadorateste.  Desde já obrigado

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem problemas, ela não é um exemplo [mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Sem as melhorias necessárias ela não resulta em uma pergunta útil para a comunidade. Sugiro ler o [Guia de Sobrevivência do SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas).

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro verifica se as chaves chaves SSH existem, e estão na sua lista

Terminal:

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
```

Depois verificar na lista se você já tem uma chave SSH pública, normalmente termina com `.pub`.

Se você receber um erro que não existem chaves, você vai precisar criar um par de chaves SSH pública e privada. E depois adicionar ao `ssh-agent`.

**Como gerar uma chave SSH**

Terminal:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "seu_email@exemplo.com"
```

Se o seu mac for antigo tente substituir `-t ed25519` por `-t rsa -b 4096`.

Depois vai pedir qual caminho você quer salvar a chave, e digite a frase secreta que você deseja, por padrão o caminho é `(/Users/you/.ssh/id_algorithm)`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu já havia gerado a chave SSH (feito no terminal do git) , criado e atribuído o conteúdo do arquivo na SSH (GitHub),ele até clona a pasta que eu solicitei clonar(somente a pasta vazia), porém ao acessar o conteúdo interno dessa pasta clonada, sempre é carregado o projeto(pasta) calculadorateste (clonado anteriormente), que não é a que eu estou tentando clonar nesse momento. A questão da chave SSH parece estar ok, o problema é que ele sempre está clonando um lixo agora (calculadorateste clonado anteriormente)